# Python Replacement of Shortcodes using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7, text, replace, shortcode

I have a string that looks like this:

```
my_str = "This sentence has a [b|bolded] word, and [b|another] one too!"
```

And I need it to be converted into this:

```
new_str = "This sentence has a <b>bolded</b> word, and <b>another</b> one too!"
```

Is it possible to use Python's `string.replace` or `re.sub` method to do this intelligently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture all the characters before `|` inside `[]` into a group . And the part after `|` into another group. Just call the captured groups through back-referencing in  the replacement part to get the desired output.

**Regex:**

```
\[([^\[\]|]*)\|([^\[\]]*)\]
```

**Replacemnet string:**

```
<\1>\2</\1>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cQ2cF4/14)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This sentence has a [b|bolded] word, and [b|another] one too!"
>>> m = re.sub(r'\[([^\[\]|]*)\|([^\[\]]*)\]', r'<\1>\2</\1>', s)
>>> m
'This sentence has a <b>bolded</b> word, and <b>another</b> one too!'
```

[Explanation...](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5C[%28[%5E%7C]*%29%5C%7C%28[%5E%5C]]*%29%5C]&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: thanks! turns out the issue I was having is not escaping the pipe '|' because it is also a special character. Really need to brush up my regex skills.

Comment: the regex: `\[([^|]*)\|([^\]]*)\]` incorectly parses: `"stuff[uh-oh!]stuff[b|bolded]stuff"` - you need to add `]` to the first negated char class. I'd also exclude the `[` to avoid problems with possibly nested brackets: i.e. `\[([^[\]|]*)\|([^[\]]*)\]`

Comment: Updated...i know that, but i'm too lazy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression: `[[]b[|](\w+)[]]` shorter version can also be `\[b\|(\w+)\]`

Where the expression is searching for anything that starts with `[b|` captures what is between it and the closing `]` using `\w+` which means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to include a wider range of characters you can also use `.*?` instead of `\w+` which will turn out in  `\[b\|(.*?)\]`

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pO5jH2/2)

**Sample Demo:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[[]b[|](\w+)[]]')
test_str = u"This sentence has a [b|bolded] word, and [b|another] one too!"
subst = u"<bold>$1</bold>"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**Output:**

*`This sentence has a <bold>bolded</bold> word, and <bold>another</bold> one too!`*

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, in case you don't want *two* problems:

#### Quick answer to your particular problem:

```
my_str = "This sentence has a [b|bolded] word, and [b|another] one too!"

print my_str.replace("[b|", "<b>").replace("]", "</b>")
# output:
# This sentence has a <b>bolded</b> word, and <b>another</b> one too!
```

This has the flaw that it will replace all `]` to `</b>` regardless whether it is appropriate or not. So you might want to consider the following:

#### Generalize and wrap it in a function

```
def replace_stuff(s, char):
    begin = s.find("[{}|".format(char))
    while begin != -1:
        end = s.find("]", begin)
        s = s[:begin] + s[begin:end+1].replace("[{}|".format(char),
            "<{}>".format(char)).replace("]", "</{}>".format(char)) + s[end+1:]
        begin = s.find("[{}|".format(char))
    return s
```

#### For example

```
s = "Don't forget to [b|initialize] [code|void toUpper(char const *s)]."

print replace_stuff(s, "code")
# output: 
# "Don't forget to [b|initialize] <code>void toUpper(char const *s)</code>."
```